# can't understand Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Angular 2 keeps Showing "App is working", but it works even if i clear the code from the VSCode editor.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

 @Component({
 selector: '',
templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

This navbar isn't working either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any additional information, it looks like you haven't given the component's metadata a selector. The selector identifies a matching HTML element in the app's index.html file to insert the component's HTML.

An example:
**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root> // <-- OUR SELECTOR ELEMENT
</body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root', // <-- MATCHING SELECTOR
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})


export class AppComponent {
    // ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!